# UI Bootstrap Typeahead ignore selected value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I'm using [Ui-Bootstrap's](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) Typeahead. I have two Typeahead fields (Origin and Destination Airport) and both takes the same data source. I want to avoid the Origin selected value in Destination listing. How can I do that?

**Origin**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="orig" typeahead="s in data | filter:$viewValue" class="form-control input-lg">
```

**Destination**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="dest" typeahead="s in data | filter:$viewValue" class="form-control input-lg">
```

I found in Google to do something like

```
ng-if="person.name_key!='FirstPerson'"
```

in the ng-repeat element but here I have no access for ng-repeat in the HTML.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `typeahead-on-select($item)` to execute a callback that will remove the selected item from the data array like this:

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="orig" typeahead="s for s in data | filter:$viewValue" 
           class="form-control input-lg" typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item)">
```

And as for the `onSelect` function -

```
  $scope.onSelect = function(item){
    $scope.data.push($scope.previouslySelected); // push back the previously selected
    $scope.previouslySelected = item; // save the currently selected
    var index = $scope.data.indexOf(item);
    $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
  };
```

Here's a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9k7CTkVMcx0RktHPfh7q?p=preview)

Comment: what i can do in case i'm retrieving data from server?